# Operator norm; vector for which $\|Ax\|_2=\|A\|_{\rm op}\|x\|_1$ holds

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $(V_1, \| \cdots \|_1)$ and $(V_2 , \| \cdots \|_2)$ be Banach spaces on the same field $K=C ,R$.
Let $\| \cdots \|_{\rm op} $ be the usual operator norm on $L_c(V_1 , V_2)$ (space of continuous linear operators).
Given $A \in L_c(V_1 , V_2)$ is it always possible to find $x \in V_1$, $x \neq 0$ such that $\|Ax\|_2=\|A\|_{op}\|x\|_1$?
I suppose no (in infinite dimensional spaces), then when is it possible? do the Banach spaces or the operator have to satisfy certain conditions? are there examples for which such $x$ doesn't exist?

Comment: What are the subscripts? Are they just norms in $V_1$, $V_2$ respectively?

Comment: $x= \mathbf{0}$ always works.

Comment: @i707107 yes. Nigel you are right, I should have written $x \neq 0$

Answer (score 2):

Define $L: l_2 \to l_2$ by  $[Lx]_k =(1-{1\over k}) x_k$.

We have $\|L\| = 1$ but there is no $x\neq 0$ for which $\|Lx\| = \|x\|$.

Comment: doesn't the equality hold for any constant sequence?

Comment: @L.R.: Thanks for catching that, I fixed the issue.

Comment: yes, it should work. I believe it's a very nice example now, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Even when $V_1$ and $V_2$ are the same Banach space and $A:V_1\to V_1$ is  continuous and linear there may be no $x\ne 0$ such that $\|Ax\|=\|A\|\cdot \|x\|.$

For example let $v\in V_1$ with $\|v\|=1.$ If there exists $f\in (V_1)^*$ with $\|f\|=1$, with the property that $$\forall x\in V_1\;(f(x)\ne 0\implies |f(x)|<\|x\|)$$ then let $A(x)=vf(x)$ for all $x\in V_1.$

For an example of such $f,$ let $V_1$ be the set of all sequences $(x_n)_n$  in $K$ (that is, in $\mathbb R$ or in $\mathbb C$) that satisfy $\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n=0$, with norm $\|(x_n)_n\|=\sup_n|x_n|.$ Let $(f_n)_n$ be a sequence in $K$ with $\sum_n|f_n|=1,$ such that $0\ne f_n$ for infinitely many $n.$ For $x=(x_n)_n\in V_1$ let $f(x)=\sum_nx_nf_n. $

Comment: What do you mean with "converge to $0$"? is $V_1$ the space of bounded sequnces or is it a different space?

Comment: I mean that a member of V_1 is a sequence of real or complex numbers that converges to the number 0. I will edit to clarify this.

Comment: ok, thank you. I think I got the idea